# Jasper strech subreport

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I have Detail band in master report with two subreports

[image: Master report]

When I form report I see that left subreport more higher then right

[image: Diff in subreport]

Subreport has such structure

[image: Structure]

How to make, that if in the report there are less lines than in other, it was stretched? Actually, the ColumnFooter band was on the same level.

Subreports attributes:

```
Position Type: Float 
Strech Type: Relatives to tallest object
Overflow Type: Strech
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided. Listed all list in one detail band to one size

Comment: Alexey, your solution is unclear. Maybe the screenshot of a new design helps others to understand your answer

Answer (score 0):

When left grid was with rows
Right didn't strech horizontaly 
[image]